# Server object error 'ASP 0178 : 80070005'

Tags: asp.net

Unable to access website  http://accesscommercialmortgages.com

Server object error 'ASP 0178 : 80070005'

Server.CreateObject Access Error

/includes/scripts/databaseconnect.asp, line 5

The call to Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is denied to this object.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

["Server object error 'ASP 0178 : 80070005'" error message when you attempt to connect to a database results page created in FrontPage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315454)

As it states in the exception, this is a permissions issue and according to the docs

> This behavior can occur if incorrect NTFS permissions are defined for your "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\System" folder.